# why does an m1 Mac think that a side loaded iOs app is jailbroken?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-silicon

I took an iPhone 11 running the latest iOs at this time (14.4.1) and connected it up to a Mac running Mojave. I pull an app out of it as an ipa file. I copied the ipa file to the M1 Mac and double clicked it. The M1 Mac then said it was installing the app! I double clicked on the installed app and it said it would run on a jailbroken iPhone?!

My iPhone is not jailbroken and the original app runs fine on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App is doing this check, not your computer. Apps use a variety of techniques, usually involving checking for the presence or lack of specific files that *indicate* the possibility of a jailbroken iPhone.

This app has implemented their check poorly, causing it to trigger on your Mac. You should contact the developers of the application and tell them to remove the jailbreaking checks.

*Note:* Of course, if the developer did not list it on the App Store they may not be receptive to making changes to accommodate running it on the Mac.

Comment: thank you. It is the RSA authentication app. It works fine on my iPhone. Of course the organization had to register it by sending me a QR code in a web browser. Now when I log in to the organization, I have to pull out  the phone, identify myself to the phone, start the app, get the code, etc. It would be a lot easier if I could use the RSA on the mac. I called the organization and they said they are not set up to use multiple 2FA devices. I really get the feeling that we will all eventually be asphyxiated by the cognitive burden imposed by our IT departments.

Answer (score -1):

The .ipa file is called as an iOS App containing jailbroken apps, Any jailbroken apps like unc0ver, AltStore and AppCake. Uninstall it before it starts jalbreaking your iPhone.